# How to get Focus in editText that is in a ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have a form with a lot of ViewSwitcher that change a TextView to an EditText with a clic.

The thing is I must clic 2 times to be able to insert value : Here are the screenshots :

[image: The first step, field is a textview]
[image: The second step, field is a edittext but without focus]
[image: The last step, field is OK]

The good thing would be not passing by the second state....

Here is my code.

```
<TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:text="Colonia:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/android_blue" />

            <ViewSwitcher
                android:id="@+id/vs2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_colonia"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="TextViewClicked"
                    android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Colonia"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_colonia"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:text="Colonia 13"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            </ViewSwitcher>
        </TableRow>
```

And here is the java part :

```
switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(switchId);
    View newView = switcher.getNextView();

    if (newView instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) newView).setText(valor);
    } else if (newView instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText) newView).setText(valor);
        ((EditText) newView).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        ((EditText) newView).requestFocus();
              getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    }
    switcher.showNext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the edittext and then formatting it,

```
viewswitcher.showNext();
edittext.requestFocus();
edittext.setSelection(edittext.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you are in a fragment

```
switcher.showNext();
edittext.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(edittext, 1);
```

If you are in an Activity

```
switcher.showNext();
edittext.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(edittext, 1);
```

A little late, but might help someone else...